# Overlapping images with setIcon

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have made a `JLabel` where I display my images like this:

```
BufferedImage myimage;
imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myimage));
```

Is it possible to draw an image and draw upon it a smaller image (an icon) with the `setIcon` command? How can I do it?

For example:

```
BufferedImage myimage1;
BufferedImage myLittleIcon;
imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myimage1));
imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myLittleIcon));
```

The above just draws the small icon.

Comment: You've provided code for `JLabel`, but you've tagged it and titled it as `JFrame` - which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `setIcon` would overwrite the icon. However, you could try something like this:

```
// Assumed that these are non-null
BufferedImage bigIcon, smallIcon;

// Create a new image.
BufferedImage finalIcon = new BufferedImage(
    bigIcon.getWidth(), bigIcon.getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)); // start transparent

// Get the graphics object. This is like the canvas you draw on.
Graphics g = finalIcon.getGraphics();

// Now we draw the images.
g.drawImage(bigIcon, 0, 0, null); // start at (0, 0)
g.drawImage(smallIcon, 10, 10, null); // start at (10, 10)

// Once we're done drawing on the Graphics object, we should
// call dispose() on it to free up memory.
g.dispose();

// Finally, convert to ImageIcon and apply.
imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(finalIcon));
```

This creates a new image, paints the big icon, and then paints the small icon.

You can also paint other things, like [outlining a rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) or [filling an oval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

For more advanced graphics functions, try casting to a [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object.

Comment: 1) Don't forget to `dispose()` of the graphics instance. 2) Please link to the docs of the latest public JRE, rather than those from 1.4.2. 3) Re. your query between `JLabel` & `JFrame` I decided since the code attribute name implied label, to tag it as such.

Comment: Why do you draw from 0,0 to 10,10 ?

Comment: That was just an example. It would draw the big image with the top-left corner at the point `(0, 0)`, and the small image with the top-left corner at `(10, 10)`. It doesn't have to do with the size. If you don't provide a size, it'll use the size of the image. If you wanted to scale it, for example, starting at (10, 15) with a width of 30 and a height of 40, you would use `drawImage(image, 10, 15, 30, 40, null)`.